# Parse Server docker-compose lockout policy

Tags: docker-compose, parse-platform

I'm trying to add lockout policy to parse platform docker-compose configuration, but encountering an error:

```
 /parse-server/lib/Config.js:235
parse        |         throw 'Account lockout duration should be greater than 0 and less than 100000';
```

Here is the piece of docker-compose:

```
  parse:
    container_name: 'parse'
    image: parseplatform/parse-server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:1337:1337'
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=random_id
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=random_key
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://mongodb/random
      - PARSE_SERVER_ENABLE_ANON_USERS=false
      - PARSE_SERVER_ALLOW_CUSTOM_OBJECT_ID=true
      - PARSE_SERVER_MOUNT_PATH=/
      - PARSE_SERVER_ACCOUNT_LOCKOUT=true
      - PARSE_SERVER_ACCOUNT_LOCKOUT_DURATION=9
      - PARSE_SERVER_ACCOUNT_LOCKOUT_THRESHOLD=6
```

Why is there an issue with duration, when it is clearly provided?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess the problem is the line with `- PARSE_SERVER_ACCOUNT_LOCKOUT=true`. Try to remove it.

Comment: When I remove it, error goes away, however account lockout does not engage. I submit 10 wrong password requests and account still active, I can login right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
parse:
    container_name: 'parse'
    image: parseplatform/parse-server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:1337:1337'
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    environment:
      - PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID=random_id
      - PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY=random_key
      - PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI=mongodb://mongodb/random
      - PARSE_SERVER_ENABLE_ANON_USERS=false
      - PARSE_SERVER_ALLOW_CUSTOM_OBJECT_ID=true
      - PARSE_SERVER_MOUNT_PATH=/
      - PARSE_SERVER_ACCOUNT_LOCKOUT={"duration":9,"threshold":6,"unlockOnPasswordReset":true}
```